# What is this error: couldn't get mapped to 10 iovecs due to fragmentation

Tags: swift, networking, error-handling

I am trying to figure out a problem with my Swift 3 app which is supposed to send asset data from an iDevice to a webserver using the `JustHTTP` framework.

I have made a different SO question which asks a little bit of a different question, so I decided to make a new question regarding an error message that is printed on the log which is not caused by the `JustHTTP` framework, but rather by underlying Apple code, because I received this error message when I hardcoded my HTTP request code using native Apple calls.

The error is

> netcore_dispatch_data_to_iovec data (360448 bytes) couldn't get mapped
>   to 10 iovecs due to fragmentation

Googling or Binging does not give me anything, at all, what so ever.

Given that the error mentions `netcore`, I'm guessing that it has something to do with networking.

What does that error mean?

Comment: I'm also facing this message when I'm uploading a big file to an HTTP server. The request body is provided by an NSInputStream which reads data from a file. Each time I have this message, the corresponding amount of data is lost (never received by the server). The request ends by a timeout error because the server waits for the entire amount of data to be received and never receives it. Seen on iOS 10.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate "Address Sanitizer"? Turning it off solved this problem for me.